How to use Xibo-cms-develop with Docker
I am undertaking a Docker install of xibo-cms-develop version 4.10 on Windows. When I try to follow the simple path as it’s mentioned on the tutorial, the localhost response is all the time 500, like something is missing.
However, I download the folder on the website and also on the official GitHub.
When I try to use the xibo-docker-master it works perfectly but the yml file on xibo-cms-develop seems to be not working for me. When I try to mix both and set up the docker-compose.yml of each folder it show me an other error:

The CMS is temporarily off-line as an upgrade is in progress. Please check with your system administrator for updates or refresh your page in a few minutes.

I put the cms_custom_files.yml into the folder but it's not working also.
Here's my docker.compose.yml file:

version: "2.1"

services:
    cms-db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes:
            - "./shared/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=cms
            - MYSQL_USER=cms
            - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
        mem_limit: 1g
        env_file: config.env
        restart: always
    cms-xmr:
        image: ghcr.io/xibosignage/xibo-xmr:0.11
        ports:
            - "9505:9505"
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 256m
        env_file: config.env
    cms-web:
        image: ghcr.io/xibosignage/xibo-cms:release-4.0.11
        volumes:
            - "./shared/cms/custom:/var/www/cms/custom"
            - "./shared/backup:/var/www/backup"
            - "./shared/cms/web/theme/custom:/var/www/cms/web/theme/custom"
            - "./shared/cms/library:/var/www/cms/library"
            - "./shared/cms/web/userscripts:/var/www/cms/web/userscripts"
            - "./shared/cms/ca-certs:/var/www/cms/ca-certs"
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_HOST=cms-db
            - XMR_HOST=cms-xmr
            - CMS_USE_MEMCACHED=true
            - MEMCACHED_HOST=cms-memcached
        env_file: config.env
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        mem_limit: 1g
    cms-memcached:
        image: memcached:alpine
        command: memcached -m 15
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 100M
    cms-quickchart:
      image: ianw/quickchart
      restart: always



Could you please post your docker-compose.yml file? IT would be grate if you provide reference links.

thx for your reply, i added the docker compose.yml to my question
